# What is equivalent display Annotation in fluent Api?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco

what is equivalent following code in fluent API?

```
[Display(Name = "توضیحات")]
public string Description { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DisplayAttribute` is not used by Entity Framework, hence there's no equivalent.