# Setting the Display Name of a model property using fluent API

Tags: entity-framework, fluent, ef-core-2.0

Is there an equivalent fluent API approach to setting the display name of a model property in ef core?  For example, how would you write the equivalent of the following in the OnModelCreating method of a dbcontext using HasAnnotation()?

```
[Display(Name = "Create Date")]
public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
```

I tried

```
entity.Property(e => e.CreateDate).HasAnnotation("DisplayName", "Create Date");
```

Comment: fluent api is for configuring the data and data type in sql and can do nothing for dot net side!

Comment: based on [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31229416/what-is-equivalent-display-annotation-in-fluent-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31229416/what-is-equivalent-display-annotation-in-fluent-api) You're not allowed to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use [override] keyword?

for instance

```
[Display(Name = "Create Date")]
public override DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score -1):

please try this.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntityName>()
                .Property(e => e.CreateDate)
                .HasColumnName("Create Date");

in OnModelCreating method.
```